# Which mongoDB ODM for C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I have recently started developing a project using C++11 and MongoDb, although i have successfully used mongocxx driver to implement the logic, but it takes some time to desiralize the data.

```
mongocxx::options::find opts;
opts.limit(15000);
mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find({},opts);

for(auto && doc : cursor) {
    bsoncxx::document::element name = doc["Name"];
    bsoncxx::document::element experience = doc["Experience"];
    bsoncxx::document::element jobTitle = experience["JobTitle"];
    bsoncxx::document::element keywords = experience["Keywords"];

    string name = name.get_utf8().value.to_string();
    string jobTitleStr = jobTitle.get_utf8().value.to_string();

    bsoncxx::array::view keyWordsarray{keywords.get_array()};

    set<string> keyWordsSet;
    for (bsoncxx::array::element msg : keyWordsarray) {
          keyWordsSet.insert(msg.get_utf8().value.to_string());
    }
}
```

The above operation takes 1.5 seconds for me. I was hoping is there any ODM present in C++ for mongoDb (like mongoengine in Python) to take care of the deserialization work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at mangrove: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mangrove

It is a mongodb-labs project, so, not officially supported, but it might show you how to approach building your own object document mapping above mongocxx.

Comment: Regrets for delay in response, but mangrove is not working for me on latest version, already posted the issue on its github long ago, do you know any other ODM too ?

Comment: @NirmalVatsyayan Can you give me a link to the github issue? I can try to get it some more visibility.

Comment: link to issue https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mangrove/issues/34

Comment: @NirmalVatsyayan The above issue is now resolved.

Comment: Sorry for super delay, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this project still alive ?